# In VBA check which excel sheet is active (currently shown)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a method of checking if an excel sheet is currently active (currently shown).
I'm interested in a synchronous method and not in an event.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use `set sh = ActiveSheet`, or `strShName = ActiveSheet.Name`.
To test if sheet Xyz is active: `If ActiveSheet.Name = "xyz" Then`
You can also use `If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet1" Then` (VBE name)

Answer (score 2):

**Test for matching worksheet and workbook names.**

```
Function IsActiveSheet(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet) As Boolean
    IsActiveSheet = targetSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Name And _
            targetSheet.Parent.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Function
```

It's a function.  Place it in a module, and then call it from another procedure like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim mySheetVar As Worksheet
    Set mySheetVar = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Here's the function call which returns TRUE or FALSE.
    MsgBox IsActiveSheet(mySheetVar)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If Sheet1 Is ActiveSheet Then

Call

ElseIf Sheet2 Is ActiveSheet Then

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.